# Apache RewriteRule woes

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to create an Apache Rewrite rule for the following condition:

Original URL:
https://somewebsite.com/GCSWEB/runSavedReport.do?mode=excel&reportID=40678
New URL:
https://somewebsite.com/demo/runSavedReport.do?mode=excel&reportID=40678

So only when a /runSavedReport.do?mode=excel&reportID=xxxxx is requested the /GCSWEB web path will be replaced with /demo.  All other parts of the URL will remain the same. I coded the following but it's not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/GCSWEB/runSavedReport\.do\?mode=excel\&reportID=([0-9]+)$ https://somewebsite.com/demo/runSavedReport.do?mode=excel&reportID=$1 [R=301,L]
```

It's also important to note I have another existing rule that is working fine that redirects any request for /GCSWEB/xxxx/xxx to /demo.  However, I want this new rule to override the existing rule if the specific URL above is called.  Any other URL will drop down to the existing rule and be redirected to simply /demo (with no other additions to the URL). The existing rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/GCSWEB/(.*) https://somewebsite.com/demo/? [R=301,L]
```

Been working on the new rule all day with no success.  I've even tried removing the existing rule thinking that there might be some conflict but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing rule that would match the URL, you should be writing your new one **on top** of that.

Also, RewriteRule **does not** match the query part of the URL. You should use instead RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mode=excel&reportID=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^/GCSWEB/runSavedReport\.do$ /demo/runSavedReport.do?mode=excel&reportID=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Also, as there is no change in protocol (`https`) neither in the domain name (`lhdata-dev.bankofamerica.com`), there is no need to specify them in the rewrite part.

Comment: Hi @Bribo if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.